# convert yaml string to function reference in nodejs module (not call the function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

For clarity.

I am working on a plugin for [hapijs](https://hapi.dev/) (17.0.0+) that will read in a yaml file of api routes, parse it into an array of [hapijs](https://hapi.dev/) valid route objects, and pass that array into the `server.route()` method in the plugin.

This is all working correctly and as I had hoped except for one small caveat, I cannot get the handler function names converted to actual function references in the objects I create during the parse phase. Because this is a plugin the normal `global[<function name>]` does not have access to the correct scope to resolve the functions in question (they live in another module, or in the main server script but would never live in this plugin) and I am desperately trying to avoid a solution that involves either `eval()` or `new Function()` due to the security concerns.

This plugin only gets called once at the beginning of server startup to load the route table so performance concerns do not really come into it, but `eval()` is a serious code smell for me and if I cannot find another solution I will end up abandoning yaml and choose another means to accomplish this task.

My two current train's of thought are to either find a way (trick) to make yaml parse a value as a literal (function name) rather than a string, or to find a way to look for the function name on the calling module's `global[]` rather than that of my own module. So far I cannot find that either of these is possible.

yaml route example:

```
- method: GET
  path: /
  description: "Test base route"
  handler: baseRoute
  tags:
    - test
    - base
- method: GET
  path: /users
  description: "Get users"
  handler: getUsers
  tags:
    - users
    - list
```

Current module implementation (with some debugging oddities still included):

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const Path = require('path');
const YAML = require('js-yaml');

module.exports = {
  pkg: require('./package.json'),
  register: async function (server, options) {

    let routeInput = null;
    let routes = [];
    fs.readFile(Path.join(__dirname, 'routes.yml'), (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        routeInput = YAML.safeLoad(data.toString(), { onWarning: (err) => { console.error(err) }, json: true });
        routeInput.forEach((r) => {
          console.log(getFunction(r.handler, server));
          routes.push({
            method: r.method,
            path: r.path,
            handler: r.handler,
            options: {
              description: r.description,
              tags: r.tags
            }
          })
        });
        server.route(routes);
      }
    });
  }
};

let getFunction = function getFunction(name, server) {

  let fn = name.toString().trim();

  console.log(fn);

  if (fn in server) {
    console.log('in global')
  }
  console.log(typeof(server));
  console.log(typeof(server[fn]));
}
```

Any suggestions or tricks to make this possible would be appreciated.

Comment: Store all of your handlers in an object, and reference them using square bracket notation. So for example, `myListOfHandlers['baseRoute']` or `myListOfHandlers['getUsers']`.

Comment: @djfdev, I thought of that but rejected for a couple of reasons. This is a plugin that will be published on npm and used (hopefully) by many programmers, not only would it be a huge violation of the single responsibility principle to do this, i literally cannot implement this without forcing every consuming programmer to pass me an object with all of their handlers attached to them. At which point I am asking for more work than I am saving them by configuring routes with yaml rather than just writing their own module of routes...

Comment: How does it violate the single-responsibility principle? I’m also not even sure how that’s relevant in the case of a public API (i.e. your users shouldn’t care or need to know about the implementation, just the API).

Comment: Also, a public API will always force your users to follow some sort of convention ... that’s just how APIs work, and why we must do things like document them. Passing in an object full of handler functions seems like a perfectly reasonable API to me. Furthermore, you’re already “forcing” your users to write these unconventional YAML config files ... how is that any different?

Comment: Single responsability means that a function (or in this case module) should only do one job and only ask for information necessary for that job. Having it hold a list of all functions that could/will be called means that now the module that actually declares those functions knows about them and this new module also has to know about them in a second place (3 total). Any updates to the list have to be made in both places making the code very loose (not cohesive) and hard to keep up with, particularly when this is an external dependency for the user, not their own code.

Comment: As to the "forcing" them to use my YAML markup that is the point of the module, if they prefer they can always build their routes by hand. The route config info is necessary for the job, submitting a list of all of your handlers in a specific format that then has to be check and validated (which you cant do because you can't reach that context and know that these are all really functions in the correct format) is not expected information to have to share. This would be like having to submit a list of tags you plan to use to jquery on initialization.

Comment: This is admittadly a preference thing (like not being willing to use eval to resolve this) and may not be possible. That is why I asked the question the way I did though, because I tried a number of approaches and have narrowed it down to several that I am not sure I can accomplish, and if I can't find a work around I will just restructure the entire endeavor to use some other means of passing in the config in the first place.

Comment: For sure, TBH I'm not super clear what your question was anyways other than looking for general advice, so it's hard to provide an answer that isn't opinion based (i.e. "how I would personally build this library/API"). I would generally suggest putting down the CS theory and/or fear of `eval` until you have something that works. Then improve on the API and implementation later. You might also take a look at ORM libs like sequelize, which use the filesystem + convention to automatically load and process model files. I could see you doing something similar here.

Comment: hapi is a ecosystem that particularly encourages config (explicit not just conventions) over code where possible, and given that I often start a project with a handful of identical routes before moving on to specialize I was hoping to do something much like the ORM model with my YAML import, but as I cannot find a way to import the handler function reference from YAML that does not include either having to have an objects file passed in or using `eval()` I will most likely go looking for some other means of passing in config that will allow for that requirement.